# Why Are My Minecraft Custom Chat Commands Not Working?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, minecraft

My Minecraft custom chat commands do not work. It gives an error when loading a world.

My code:

```js
import { world } from '@minecraft/server';
world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe((eventData) => {
    const player = eventData.sender;
    switch (eventData.message) {
        case '!creative':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            player.runCommandAsync('gamemode c');
            break;
        case '!survival':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            player.runCommandAsync('gamemode s');
            break;
        default: break;
    }
});
```

When loading a world this error message appears:

`[Scripting][error]-Plugin [Custom Commands - 1.0.0] - [index.js] ran with error: [TypeError: cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined    at <anonymous> (index.js:3)]`

Does anyone know how to fix this as there is not much documentation available online?

I tried to create a script so that when I send `!creative` into chat it changes my gamemode to creative (and vice versa for `!survival` )

I expected everything would work fine as i found multiple tutorials and even tried just copy-pasting the code, but what actually happened is I got an error message above.

Minecraft version I am using is Bedrock Edition Release 1.20.40

Comment: The error means that `world.beforeEvents.chatSend` is `undefined`. I don't know why that would be the case, but that's the direct cause of the problem.

Comment: Did you enable the api `@minecraft/server` in your `manifest.json`? `"dependencies":[{"module_name": "@minecraft/server","version": "1.7.0"}]` (1.7.0 is the latest stable version). If you are, then I don't know what the problem could be. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your manifest.json file in your behavior pack that you have the "@minecraft/server" module listed in the dependencies, and that you also have the correct version listed.